# Form not submitting on mobile phone after deploying to heroku but works on laptop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, redux

I deployed my mern app on heroku, and everything works fine I am able to "Sign In" via the form,  while testing the web app on my laptop. However, when I try to "Sign In" on the app on my phone, it does not work. When I tried debugging it, I realized that when I click on the 'submit function, it stops where I sent the form data to the backend.

Here is my Submit function

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      email,
      password,
    };

    await login(data) // the function stops here

    navigate('/');
  };
```

Here  is the login function below,

```
export function login(userdata) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const loggedInUser = await axios.post(
        `${BASE_URL}/carers/login`,
        userdata
      );

      let { data } = loggedInUser;

      localStorage.setItem('Authtoken', data.token);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(data.user));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      localStorage.removeItem('Authtoken');
      dispatch(setCurrentUserFailure());
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: how about trying to debug in login function.  specifically, check this line.
`${BASE_URL}/carers/login`,
        userdata

Comment: instead of fancy checking  just try simple if else and try to login. this way you can narrow down if there is a problem with deployment or not.